# Updating SQL Server 2008 LOGIN SID

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, authentication, active-directory

If an Active Directory SID doesn't match the 
 `SQL Server 2008`
 Login SID (`sys.server_principal`) there doesn’t appear to be a way to ALTER/UPDATE that value.  `ALTER USER` will allow you to remap a USER to a LOGIN, but `ALTER LOGIN` will not allow you to remap a LOGIN to Active Directory so to my question…

Is there any way, documented or otherwise, to update the LOGIN SID with the AD SID besides dropping and recreating the login?  I am using `OPENROWSET` to get the AD SID value, but I can't find a way to update the LOGIN SID (mostly because I don't think it can be done)

By the way, I am aware that ad-hoc queries to the system tables are not allowed (because I tried that already).

Answer (score 3):

I'm certain there is not.  You can use [sp_change_users_login](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174378.aspx) to re-map the SID between a 'user' and a 'login' - but reading your question it sounds like you already know that.

While you can use [sp_validatelogins](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181728.aspx) to find out if there are any sql login's that are orphaned (not mapped to valid windows account) the only process Micorsoft offers is what you've already guessed... dropping the orphaned login, and creating a new one.  All documentation I have on resolving orphaned logins after they've been identified is to "drop the login".

The lack of this ability to me is probably more of a security concern than a missing "feature".  I can imagine a variety of scenarios where changing out the login SIDs would be considered very shady behavior.  Imagine I wanted to do something and make it look like it was another user.  Swap out the SIDs... do my nefarious behavior... swap them back.

Answer (score 3):

Answer 1 is correct, it would be shady.

One upside of remapping a login SID to a different AD SID is it would enable an administrator to implement role based authentication.  A database user could be defined as user = "financial_officer" (FO) in multiple database and/or multiple servers, then be placed in multiple groups, and then views that join to lookup tables could be created to provide appropriate row level security.  Then when the FO retires or quits, the SID of the "financial_officer" login could be swapped out to immediately provide the privileges of the old FO to the new FO.

It was my hope that User_Created_Server_Level_Roles&UCSRL/SLR) (something I suggested to MS) would enable this ability, and it can, but only if a single login can be added to a UCSLR.  Then a TSQL function would be needed to return SLR as "USER" AND "SYSTEM_USER" now do.

If SQLServer provided a Server_Level_Position_Role, pure role based authentication could be implemented in SQLServer.  Under this scenario a login SID change is all that would be required to backfill a position with another person.

This is possible now by visiting each database and changing the FO SID to the SID of the person (AD SID) of the person backfilling the FO position.